# How do I populate a DropDownList with a blank and html attributes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

I've setup my drop down list in the following manner.  However, I can't seem to get both a blank string in the drop-down-list & html attributes to set a class.

**Controller**

```
 Dim items As IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem) = _
     db.Persons.[Select](Function(m) New  _
     SelectListItem() With { _
       .Value = m.ID.ToString(), _
       .Text = m.LastName & ", " & m.FirstName}).OrderBy(Function(n) n.Text)
 ViewBag.AllPlayers = items
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("AllPlayers", "")
```

*Also tried...*

```
@Html.DropDownList("AllPlayers", Nothing, New With { .class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
@Html.DropDownList("AllPlayers", New SelectList(New List(Of Object){ 
                   New { value = "" , text = ""  },
                }, "value", "text"), New With { .class = "form-control" })
```

I am not very familiar with VB.NET syntax, but I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how I missed this initially. However, here is what I used that works.

```
@Html.DropDownList("AllPlayers", Nothing, "", New With {.class = "form-control"})
```